# H2 database bulk upload

Tags: h2

I have a task to load some data from mysql to h2. We have to render a tree at the UI level where the tree has more around 50000 nodes. So thinking that reading from H2 might reduce the delay.

For that, I have to load around 1M (every customer has their own tree) records to H2 from MySQL. The loading part is handle by the application. Where it reads from MySQL and do batch updates to H2. It processes 40000 records at a give execution. But the server goes out of memory as the migration process continues.

I have tried using "SET LOG 0, SET LOCK_MODE 0, SET UNDO_LOG 0" to efficiently load data but still the same the server goes out of memory.

I have set 512M memory for heap.

The H2 document says to use "create table ... as select ..." to load data faster but I think that will not reduce the load time since the application has to read the 1M records and create a CSV file.

Can somebody suggest a way ?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid having to create CSV files, you could create [linked tables](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#linked_tables) using the [`CREATE LINKED TABLE`](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_linked_table) statement or using [`CALL LINK_SCHEMA`](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#link_schema). Then copy the data using `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT`.

As for the memory problem, do you create an in-memory database? If yes, you could conserve memory (at the expense of some speed) if you use the [in-memory file system, or the compressed in-memory file system](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#file_system): `jdbc:h2:memFS:test` or `jdbc:h2:memLZF:test` instead of `jdbc:h2:mem:test`. If you are not using an in-memory database then I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Hi Thomas. Thank you for your valuable comment. I am using embedded database. I modified the code to support load data from Linked tables. Fortunately the time taken to load through linked table and my present implementation are approximately same. I have integrated the support for linked table also for future situations. Thank you.